# Nativescript 6.1.1 Application crashes in --release mode, works in debug

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a Nativescript Vue application that will no longer run in release mode.

I recently migrated the app from 5.3.0 to 6.1.1 and everything seemed fine.  I did several updates including adding `nativescript-admob` and `nativescript-purchase` and corresponding functionality.  Again, all continues to be fine when debugging the app in both ios and android.

I am also able to successfully build in --release mode for android and archive with iOS.  However, when I go to run the app that is generated on android, it crashes immediately on startup.

Here is a gist containing my package.json, with app ids etc changed: https://gist.github.com/wpatter6/3575e029572eaedb03e723d5fba19e10

Here's a gist containing the logcat stacktrace that is thrown every time the app tries to start up:
https://gist.github.com/wpatter6/3ec8def984e5e0ef532653c149020804

Here is the script I'm running to build:

```
rm -rf platforms/android
rm -rf node_modules

npm i

tns build android --env.snapshot --env.sourceMap --bundle --clean --release --key-store-*
```

I'm at a loss for how to proceed with troubleshooting this or what this stack trace could be pointing to.

If anyone has suggestions for how to get more information out of the logs or what the issue could be, I'd appreciate the help.  Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I tried building it with the `--env.snapshot` flag and that is now throwing an error which says `The file ./app.css couldn't be loaded! You may need to register it inside ./app/vendor.ts`.  This project uses scss, perhaps there is something wrong there?  Strange that it's only an issue in release mode, styling works great in debug...

Comment: Did you use android device monitor for the logs? If not can you use that and try to show the entire crash log. The one you have attached seems to be debug log, doesn't contain any detail about the errors / exceptions.

Comment: The log I posted was captured using the logcat viewer in Android Studio running on an emulated device.  I'm not familiar with Android Device Monitor but google docs says it's deprecated (https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor). Can you give me more info about the tool to get more info out of the logs @Manoj?

Comment: @Manoj Here's an updated stack trace with possibly some more info: https://gist.github.com/wpatter6/3ec8def984e5e0ef532653c149020804

Comment: nativescript-purchase is now part of proplugins. In the [readme](https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-purchase#readme) it states that it only supports pre-Nativescript 6. I'm not sure that's causing your error though.

Comment: Man I wish I could help you because I ran into a similar issue. In my case I'm using nativescript angular, and the --env.aot solved my issues. You could try creating a new project on nativescript 6, and look for the differences in structure with your project (AndroidManifest, Gradle, etc.). Good luck man! You should post your answer when you find it.

Comment: Hmm strangely I can't run the `tns plugin add @proplugins/nativescript-purchase` command, it gives an error `404 Not Found: @proplugins/nativescript-purchase@latest`

Comment: You will need a payed subscription for that (https://proplugins.org/subscribe.html).

Comment: @Tim I see.  I just wish there was a way to know for sure that is what is causing this error, I'd hate to pay for something and have this continue to occur...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've narrowed down the issue here.  It is in the minification/obfuscation that I was doing which is detailed for Android [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).

Here is the current version of piece in my `app.gradle` with the 
buildTypes property that is apparently causing the issue commented out:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "com.willweb.clicker"
  }
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
  /* buildTypes { // THIS CAUSES RELEASE MODE ERROR ON APP LAUNCH
    release {
      // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
      // your project's release build type.
      minifyEnabled true

      // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
      // Android Gradle plugin.
      shrinkResources true

      // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
      // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
      // R8 configuration files.
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
        'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  } */
}
```

Fortunately, removing this does allow me to build and run the app in release mode, but unfortunately with a much larger file size.

There exists [this question](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/440) regarding proguard from a couple of years ago, but there is no update regarding that.

According to their team in github NativeScript provides tools to optimize the app size and code like Uglifing, AOT (for Angular), Snapshots (only for release Android build on MAC) and Webpack (enabled by default).  An example of this build would be:

```
tns run android --env.uglify --env.aot --env.snapshot --releae <release-params-follows-here>
```

Comment: Can you upload that to Google Play though, since it is not signed?